# Does a Non deterministic TM halt after the same number of steps on the same input?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, turing-machines, nondeterminism

Let $M$ be a Turing Machine (TM) which decides a certain language.  Enter an input $x$ to $M$ and let the machine compute on $x$. After some time, $M$ will halt.

If $M$ is a deterministic TM, it will obviously halt at the same step on the same input.

Suppose $M$ is a non deterministic TM. Does $M$ halt after the same number of steps on the same input ?

Comment: this is better suited to [Mathematics.SE]

Comment: You should read the first two chapters of the textbook by Arora & Barak ([draft](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Compbook/Draft)) where TM and NDTM are defined. My short answer to your questions is *no*. But you can often build from a NDTM build a new one with all paths (accepting and rejecting) of same length. *Often* does not mean anything of course, but what I meant is that if you consider a NDTM deciding a language in time $f(n)$ for some nice function $f$ (time-constructible for instance), then it is possible. Of course, you can also build TM with very chaotic behaviors.

Comment: @Bruno , Tks for the reference (I already read it actually) and your comment. Yes, it is often possible to build a TM with all paths of same lenght. But, it doesn't really answer the question which holds essentially when all paths are not of the same lenght. I thought (wrongly) that a NDTM "tried" each  non deterministic possibility at each step, and then halts as soon as possible.

Comment: @XavierLabouze You really need to think of a NDTM as an unrealistic model. It accepts a word *if it has a way to do so*. This is very different from a probabilistic TM for instance.

Comment: @bruno, you are right, tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on how you define the computation process. If you consider that the TM executes all possible computations at the same time ("in parallel", if you want) and *then* decides if accepts by looking at the states in which it finished, then obviously it will always halt after the same number of steps for a given input, or never halt at all.

On the other hand, if you define a *run* of the TM as one possible execution, and define that the TM *accepts* a word if there exists *a* run that ends in an accepting state, then the answer is "no", and it should be pretty simple to define a TM which halts after different number of steps for the same input on different runs (for example, one that accepts in a run, but ends in an infinite loop in other run).

Comment: Tks for your answer. That is exactly the point : is there a unique definition of computation process ? Why not use your first one instead of the second one ?

Comment: One reason is that nondeterminism is easier to explain when you have the idea of "guessing": the TM *guesses* a path that will accept. Formally, that is defined with a *run*, not with a parallel execution of all possible runs.